# periodic sending of a client request

Tags: go, http

I have a simple project structure:

```
 .../internal/app/api
 .../internal/app/middleware
 .../internal/app/service
 .../internal/app/server
```

All incoming request handlers are located in the ...api.But now I need to periodically send a request to another service myself. "....server" contains all my routes.I wrote a function for this.

```
func SendOrderNumber(orderNumber string, endpoint string) (*model.Answer, error) {
    //endpoint example: http://localhost:8080/api/orders/
    endpointWithOrderNumber := fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", endpoint, orderNumber)
    client := &http.Client{}

    request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, endpointWithOrderNumber, strings.NewReader(""))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if response.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return nil, errors.New(response.Status)
    }

    defer response.Body.Close()
    var accrualSystemAnswer model.AccrualSystemAnswer
    err = json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&accrualSystemAnswer)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &accrualSystemAnswer, nil
}
```

I don't understand where is the best place for me to call my send request function somewhere. And how to do it.

Comment: It is better to locate this code `defer response.Body.Close()` right after error checking and before  `if response.StatusCode != http.StatusOK ...`

Answer (score -1):

you just need to pass parent context to my context.WithTimeout instead of context.Background().
Not clear about your project structure, but better to put this code together with endpoints.

```
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Minute)
    defer cancel()
    
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        // defer func() {if e := recover(); e != nil {}}() // if need to recover panic
        t := time.NewTicker(time.Hour * 1) // ticker, run 1 time per hour
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done(): //if job works too long
                return
            case <-t.C: //implement logic here, that will be called by ticker
            }
        }
    }()
```

and fix your func to make request

```
    func SendOrderNumber(ctx context.Context, orderNumber string, endpoint string) (*model.Answer, error) {
    //endpoint example: http://localhost:8080/api/orders/
    endpointWithOrderNumber := fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", endpoint, orderNumber)
    client := &http.Client{}

    request, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodPost, endpointWithOrderNumber, strings.NewReader(""))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if response.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return nil, errors.New(response.Status)
    }

    var accrualSystemAnswer model.AccrualSystemAnswer
    err = json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&accrualSystemAnswer)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // body must be closed after error check, cos in case if body is empty u will get 
    // nil body. resp.Body.Close() for nil body -> panic
    defer response.Body.Close()

    return &accrualSystemAnswer, nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with periodically sending the request)) But I still don't understand where in the project I should do it.